# Compare Raw Image Data PHP

Tags: php, image, compare

I'm trying to make a PHP script that updates photos. I receive the raw image data from the source, and I want to compare it to the existing file I have to see if I should download it. I'll post the idea of what I'm looking to do.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($directory);
$new_photo = Photo["Data"];
echo strcmp($liph_id_contents,$photo['Data']==0);
```

This doesn't work, but I hope you get the idea. The images I am trying to compare are .jpg

Photo["Data"] is raw image data

$directory is the location of a stored image file

**Update**: I'm able to convert the two images in to PHP image resources. A comparison between image resources would also suffice.

**Update**: I found a class to use to compare two image resources in PHP. Take a look at http://compareimages.nikhazy-dizajn.hu/ I made a slight change to the compare function in the class to let it take PHP image resources instead.

Comment: Well, you are missing a closing ) after strcmp...if we can start at something first

Comment: Woops! That was not an issue in my program.

Comment: just kidding, i've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a class to use to compare two image resources in PHP. Take a look at http://compareimages.nikhazy-dizajn.hu/ I made a slight change to the compare function in the class to let it take PHP image resources instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use  sha1_file() instead, like you do when you download software from the internet and want to veryfy it has not been altered.

```
if (sha1_file($directory) == sha1_file(Photo["Data"])) 
   echo "indentical";
else
   echo "not identical";
```

If both files are identical they will return the same hash.

Comment: Beat me too it. This is exactly what hashes were made for.

Comment: Photo["Data"] is the raw data of the image I'm receiving and sha1_file() wants a directory name. Is there a way to get around this without actually creating a file to store the contents? I think sha1() command would work, I will update momentarily.

Comment: echo sha1_file($directory) == sha1($Photo["Data"]);
This seems to always be false.

Comment: well, then use sha1(Photo["Data"]) for the string and sha1_file($directory) for the file....haven't tested it, but it should work

Comment: if(sha1_file($directory) == sha1($photo["Data"]))

This comparison seems to not be consistent. Some are found to be identical through this method, but the majority are not. Very odd.

Comment: Ok, then what about this:  if( sha1(file_get_contents($directory)) == sha1($photo["Data"])) .......i think, it should work there.

Comment: That comparison seems to be inconsistent as well. Some are matching and some are not when all the images are identical. Without altering my own images and after running it through multiple times, individual entries seem to match sometimes and not match others.